# How to validate that an object (whose locator we don't know since it is not present) is not present in a page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Let's say I want to verify that an upload button is not present in a page. I cannot use any locator here since I don't know the object locator value. So how do I assert in my test that it is never present?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assert that particular element is not displayed?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/39018/how-to-assert-that-particular-element-is-not-displayed)

Comment: Saurav, do you mean the button is **never** present? If not, you can either use the locator is should have if it was there and check for the not displaying. If that's the case, I can make it an answer, placing the code.

Comment: Is there a *specific button* you want to check the absence of? If so, why don't you know how you'd locate it if it was present? If not, why are you testing that an unknown button isn't there; why *might* it be?

Comment: I think this question is more general and better left open than the downvoted code and error dump that the linked question basically is. I'm voting to leave this one open and close the other as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 2):

Normally "upload button" is a [HTML input of type `file`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_file.asp) which looks like:

```
<input type="file" ...... >
```

So you need to verify whether at least 1 input of type `file` is present at the page. It can be done using the following [XPath selector](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727):

```
//input[@type='file']
```

Example code ([Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/))

```
file_upload_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")

if (len(file_upload_elements) > 0):
    print('File upload input is present')
else:
    print('File upload input is absent')
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there is no such thing as `I can not use any locator here`. An (assumed) upload button is part of the DOM and can be located in some way.

Maybe the button is always in the same place, so you can check if `By.css(".container button")` is present. Maybe you can ask the devs to provide a better locator. Or you could count the visible buttons on the page, maybe these are pretty constant so a +1 change would mean the button is present.

If maybe the button text is always the same you could use something like `driver.findAll(By.css("button")).stream().filter(e -> e.getText().equals("buttontext")).count() == 0`

There are definitely more ways, but I hope these ideas give you a direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java

```
 boolean textPresent = false;   
 try {
 if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Update’)]”))){
   textPresent = true;
 } catch (Exception e) {
   textPresent = false; 
 }
```

Using Ruby with capybara

```
expect(Capybara.current_session).to have_content('Update')
```